# oracle ExecuteXmlReader fails

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to use oracle's ExecuteXmlReader method as below:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
string query = "select xmltype('<bookstore><book>Candide</book></bookstore>') from dual;";
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandTimeout = QUERY_TIMEOUT;
XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader(); // <============== this is failing

System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Stack trace:

```
StackTrace = "   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()
at MyCompany.Test.Shared.ManagedOracle.ExecSync(String connectionString, String methodName, String query)
in v:\\MyApp\\Shared\\ManagedOracle.cs:line 52"
```

I do not know why it fails. Any ideas?
The same query works fine in oracle development tool.
Also, other methods such as ExecuteReader work fine.
There is no inner exception to include here.

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Please add the stacktrace

Comment: in oracle don't you need a a way to return the data.. for example when running in C# you need something like the following I would think `cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: How are you catching the exception?  If you can catch an `OracleException` it should help you out with an ORA-nnn error.  If its an oracle problem (and the code posted looks OK) it will help diagnose the issue.